# Get all repeated objects from an array and leave only the ones that meet certain criteria

Tags: arrays, swift

I know how to get all unique items from an array but I'm really struggling with getting the actual repeated objects to interact with them to determine which of the repeated objects can stay and which can be deleted.

Here is what I need.

```
let dogs = [Dog(name: "Teddy", inUse: true), 
            Dog(name: "Teddy", inUse: false), 
            Dog(name: "Browny", inUse: true), 
            Dog(name: "Mia", inUse: true), 
            Dog(name: "Browny", inUse: false)]
```

1. Get all repeated objects.

   `Teddy, Teddy, Browny, Browny // presorting output`
2. Check all repeated objects to find out if they're `inUse`, if they are, leave them and delete the rest.

   `Teddy, Browny // final output`

Comment: And if there are 4 Teddy, with 2 inUse true, and 2 false?

Comment: What code do you have for the first part? The second part should be as simple as `filter { $0.inUse }` .

Comment: Else `let output: [Dog] = Dictionary(grouping: dogs) { $0.name }.values.compactMap { guard $0.count > 1 else { return nil }; return $0.first { aDog in aDog.inUse }}` might do the trick... If order isn't important

Comment: Group into a dictionary, filter out anybody with a value.count <= 1 , then remove all the ones that aren’t in use.

Comment: @Larme - I actually need to list all repeated and `inUse`. Thanks

Comment: @MartinR - The first part is actually the one I'm struggling with, not sure how to get only the repeated objects.

Comment: LOL, you still don't trust the more efficient way to avoid duplicates by checking **before** inserting a new object.

Comment: @vadian - As I said in my latest reply in the other thread, duplicates will exist in a device that was previously synced or in a second device since at the start there will be no items and the items will be created and then if the user turns sync On, there will be nothing to stop from duplicating.  I rather have a system that can clean duplicates. But as I said, I really like your way of preventing duplicates so I left your answer as the correct one.

Comment: `Dictionary(grouping: dogs, by: \.name).filter { $0.value.count > 1 }.flatMap.{ $1.filter(\.inUse) }`, this will give you an array of repeated objects where inUse is true

Comment: @JoakimDanielson - I get **Anonymous closure argument not contained in a closure** on `flatMap.{$1.filter(\.inUse)}`. Thanks.

Comment: There is a dot after flatMap that you need to remove. A copy/paste error on my part.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson -  It did the trick. Add this as an answer to mark it as the correct answer.  `var repeatedDogs: [Dog] = Dictionary(grouping: dogs, by: \.name).filter { $0.value.count > 1 }.flatMap{ $1.filter(\.inUse) }`